# Studying for qualifying exams. Complex analysis identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am currently studying for my qualifying exam and I am having real difficulty with the following question. I need to find the value of the following integral for the path below. $$\displaystyle\int\limits_\gamma \frac{2z+1}{e^{\pi z}-1}dz$$ I have attempted to use the residue theorem but I don't know how to break up the regions of the integral, or how to sum them. I am also having difficulty applying said theorem to this case. I have solved such things with unit circle paths but this one is tough. Any ideas on how to solve this?

**The path:
[image: This is the path]

Comment: You just need to find all singularities enclosed by the path. You get a singularity if the denominator is $0$, so $\mathrm e^{\pi z}=1$. That's the case iff $\pi z=2\pi\mathrm ik$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$, so $z=2\mathrm i k$. Of those, only $0$ and $2\mathrm i$ are enclosed. So you need to calculate the residues at those two singularities, then apply the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to compute this.

> Residue Theorem: $$ \int_\gamma \frac{2z+1}{e^{\pi z}-1} dz = 2\pi i \sum\limits_{k=1}^n Res(f,a_k)$$ where $a_k$ are all possible singular
> points inside $\gamma$, and $Res(f,a_k)$ is the residue at $a_k$.

Here for this integrand $f=\frac{2z+1}{e^{\pi z}-1}$, there are only 2 singular points inside your $\gamma$, i.e. $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 2i$. We need to find the residue of them respectively.

For $a_1 = 0$, since $e^{\pi z}-1 = \sum_{n=1} \frac{(\pi z)^n}{n!}$, thus $Res(f,a_1) = \frac{2*0+1}{\pi} = \frac{1}{\pi}$.

For $a_2 = 2i$, since $e^{\pi z}-1 = e^{\pi (z-2i)} - 1 = \frac{(\pi z-2\pi i)^n}{n!}$, thus $Res(f,a_2) = \frac{2* 2i +1}{\pi}$.

So
$$ \int_\gamma \frac{2z+1}{e^{\pi z}-1} dz = 2\pi i (\frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{4i+1}{\pi}) = -8+4i$$